# Equal frequency binning for circular data in R

Tags: r, frequency, circular-dependency, binning, degrees

I am trying to divide my wind direction data into four equal frequency bins, without having a fixed break at 0° / 360°.
I am aware of the `equal_freq()` function from the *funModeling* package, but this function does not take the circular nature of the wind data into account and calculates the breaks by starting at 0° and ending at 360°.

Is there a way to calculate dynamic equal frequencies that can span over the null jump between 0 and 360 degrees?

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
wind_dirs<-runif(n=2000, min=0, max=360) #create a homogenous wind direction distribution
equal_freq(wind_dirs, 4) #this has a fixed break at 0° / 360°
```

I tried the *circular* package in R, but there is no function for equal frequency binning.
I also considered manually defining a breakpoint, e.g. the most prevailing direction, but this creates about the same problem as a break at 0°.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The problem with this is that if you _have_ to specify one of the break points if you are dealing with circular data. In your example, there are 2000 data points, so we should end up with 4 bins, each containing 500 points. Assuming no two points are equal, there are exactly 500 different ways to split these data into 4 equal-sized bins, and they are all equally valid. You could choose your initial break randomly from a 360 degree circle if you wanted, but why would you? What's wrong with starting at 0?